# How to add another function to JavaScript closeFullscreen?

Tags: javascript, html, web, events, bootstrap-4

I have this page where I want the buttons to disappear when a user opens a full-screen mode and then reappear again when the full-screen mode is closed.

Full code is on my github so I'm also putting link down below.
[https://github.com/bronnyhub/minimalistic-clock]

I tried to use the same method as I did in disappearing icons but it didn't work.

I also tried to use event.key to escape key but it works only when I press the key second time, not at the same time as full-screen mode is closing.

```js
var elem = document.documentElement;

function openFullscreen() {
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
    document.getElementById("expand").style.opacity = "0";
    document.getElementById("menu").style.opacity = "0";
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Safari */
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE11 */
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  const key = event.key; // Or const {key} = event; in ES6+
  if (key === "Escape") {
    document.getElementById("expand").style.opacity = "1";
    document.getElementById("menu").style.opacity = "1";
  }
});

function closeFullscreen() {
  if (document.exitFullscreen) {
    document.exitFullscreen();
    alert("Press ESC again for icons to show.");
  } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) { /* Safari */
    document.webkitExitFullscreen();
  } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) { /* IE11 */
    document.msExitFullscreen();
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm">
      <button class="bttn-menu" id="menu"><img src="menu.png"></button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm">
      <button onclick="openFullscreen()" class="bttn-expand" id="expand"><img src="expand.png" class="expand" id="expand"></button>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the problem, buttons disappear but do not re-appear on closing?

Comment: I'd handle this via CSS instead of JavaScript ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:fullscreen